# Problem with Lyx ! Numbering theorem, example, definition and proposition by type doesn't work within class IEEE journal!

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I want to make the numbering of Theorems, propositions, examples and definitions independent in my article. It should appear like:

Theorem 1
 ....................
 Proposition 1
 ....................
 Theorem 2
 ....................
 Example 1
 ....................
 Definition 1
 ....................

Not like the default dependent numbering of Lyx. The problem is that I can not activate the option Numbering by type on Setting-> Modules-> Theorem by type, it is disabled. I have verified the existing of all modules of Lyx theorems. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please stop shouting at us. We can hear perfectly well without. Please provide a minimal working example i.e. code for a complete but minimal document demonstrating the issue. Preferably a `.tex` file. Failing that, a `.lyx` file. (More people can help if you post `.tex` code.)

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  on the list, there seems to be an option "ams, number by type".  that *is* the `amsthm` default.  did you try that?

Comment: @amsthm thanks, Yes "ams, number by type" is selected as shown in the screanshoot. It is not added, and i cannot add it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  thanks, Yes "ams, number by type" that i selected as shown in the screanshoot the problem is that It is not added, and i cannot add it too.

Comment: since i'm not a lyx user, i'm afraid i can't offer any better suggestion.  hope someone else can.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, the problem is on Lyx editor, and now i'm realising that when i'm using the class of IEEE articles (IEEE journal model) i get this issue, and when i use another class, the option "ams, number by type" is selectable.

Comment: It seems to be showing you options for lots of classes and packages, but you can only select those compatible with what you're using. At least, that's my guess. I don't use LyX and I don't read the language in the screenshot.

Comment: @cfr yes i agree, but i believe that theris a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i Found a suitable solution for this problem. In order to have the theorem  numbering by type (the numbering of theorems, propositions, examples, exercises ..etc will be independent) you should:

1. Open the `.lyx` file of your IEEE paper on a text editor like "Bloc-notes"
2. Under this line `\use_default_options false` add those three lines of code and save:

`\begin_modules
  theorems-bytype 
 \end_modules`

3. Re-open your `.lyx` file on Lyx editor and the numbering will be independent.

So Since we cannot add the module for numbering by type in Lyx editor (while we are working on IEEE classes), adding it directly in the source code will be a helpfull solution.